# If an object is moving with a constant velocity, how would you find the force needed to stop the object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision

For example, if a block with a mass of 5 kg is moving a straight line at a constant velocity of 10 m/s, and stops after hitting a wall, what is the force that the wall exerts on the block?

Comment: Any unbalanced force—any at all, no matter how small—will stop it eventually. To understand the collision scenario you need more information: in particular you need to know how the two objects deform and break.

Comment: Force is proportional to acceleration which is the rate of change of velocity with respect to time but you've not stipulated the time over which the block comes to a stop.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri OK, here is the question from my homework problem: a 2 kg block slides with a speed of 3 m/s on a frictionless surface, until it encounters a spring attacked to a wall. Everything is horizontal. The spring is compressed 8 cm before the block comes to a stop. How can I find the spring constant if I don't know the elastic potential energy?

Comment: Hjllo, what makes you think you don't know the elastic potential energy? Also, describing the situation as "hitting a wall" when you know the impact behavior is elastic makes the problem sound harder than it is...

Comment: @dmckee Hey, sorry if I was being a bit ambiguous before. My original question was: a 2 kg block slides with a speed of 3 m/s on a frictionless surface, until it encounters a spring attacked to a wall. Everything is horizontal. The spring is compressed 8 cm before the block comes to a stop. I just need to find the spring constant, but I've finally figured it out. So its OK now

Answer (score 1):

The force that the wall exerts to stop the mass of 5kg is not a single force but an *impulse force* equal to the linear momentum $\vec P=m\vec v=5·10kg·m/s$ of the mass. Thus $$P=50kg·m/s=-\int \vec F dt$$ where $\vec F$ is the force exerted by the wall on the mass during the time interval from impact till the mass stops. This time integral is the impulse force of the wall on the mass required to stop it.